# Unescaped pug attribute not processed by laravel blade

Tags: laravel, pug

I'm using Laravel Pug https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-pug, and the file is named *.pug.blade.php. I'm trying to set an attribute value.

```
|   <?php $x = "any"; ?>
div(class!="{{ $x }}")
    |   {{ $x }}
```

the output html is

```
<div class="{{ $x }}">any</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `div(class!="{{ <?php echo $x; ?> }}")`?

Comment: @kmgt it does the same <div class="{{ <?php echo $x; ?>}}">any</div>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interestingly, in attribute, the php variable is accessed with no < ? php ? > or {{ }} enclosures, just like javascript variables

```
|   <?php $x = "any"; ?>
div(class=$x)
    |   {{ $x }}
```

the HTML output

```
<div class="any">any</div>
```

Also, the dollar sign can be omitted, and interpolation can be used

```
|   <?php $x = "any"; ?>
div(class = x + "test")
    |   {{ $x }}
```

the HTML output

```
<div class="anytest">any</div>
```